# Passing generic class type/constructor instead of instance as parameter

Tags: flowtype

Let's say we have a file with this class in it:

```
class Foo<T> {
  bar: T;
  constructor(bar: T) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

function getFooType() {
    return Foo;
}
```

In another file, the return value of `getFooType()` gets passed in:

```
function baz(fooType: ???) {
  let foo1 = new fooType<number>(1);
  let foo2 = new fooType<string>("2");
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what should go into `???`.

The natural choice would be `Class<Foo<T>>`, but that forces you close the `T` by doing `baz<T>(...)`, whereas I want it to stay open; you'll get errors like "Cannot construct non-polymorphic `Foo` [1] with type arguments." where you do `new fooFactory<...>()`

So the other obvious choice is using `Class<Foo>`, but then you get the error "Cannot use `Foo` [1] without 1 type argument." on that parameter.

In fact, it looks like it's not possible to pass a class' type around if it has a generic type specifier. Is that right? If so, that's very disappointing.

Comment: Can you please specify the `fooType` content in your code ? Is it a constructor function or a class ? Because I don't see how _"the return value of getFooType() gets passed in"_ in your current code.

Comment: It's not specified because I don't know what to put there to get it to work. As for the how: dependency injection — the return value of `getFooType` (i.e the class `Foo`) gets automagically passed into `baz(...)` for me by my framework. Not that I see why the how actually matters.

Answer (score 0):

So you just have to describe the typings the same way you call your factory function:

```js
function baz(fooType: <T>(bar: T) => Foo<T>) {
  let foo1 = new fooType<number>(1);
  let foo2 = new fooType<string>("2");
}
```

***Note:***

*Knowing that it uses a dependency injection mechanism was in fact quite important since that solves the issue of the generic declaration. However `<T>` means that `typeof T` equals `any`. You should specify something more accurate like `<T: number | string>`.*